# File.Create() can't be executed because file is still used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I try to create a file after checking if the directory exists, and if the file exists.

But When my program gets to this line I get the error that I can't create the file because it's already being used by another process.
The weird thing is that it shouldn't.
Even when the file doesn't exist.

```
File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile).Close()
```

the error occurs in this part of the code, catch not included.
I know that I should have used Using() but This should work too.
I don't fancy to redo this part that way untill it works this way.

```
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels"))
            {
                connection.Logger.Log("making " + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels", false, LogMode.Info);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels");
            }

            string saveFile = Program.RemoveForbiddenFileCharacters(this.ChannelName + ".Channel");
            string saveFilePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile;

            FileStream fileStream = null;
            StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile))
                {
                    File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile);
                }

                File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile).Close();

                streamWriter = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile);

                //safe stuff to file
                streamWriter.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
```

Comment: It is likely the bug you encounter isn't in the part you suspect, blipman.

Comment: For goodness' sake, put the file path in a variable at the start of the routine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've just deleted the file, then the OS might prevent you from creating it within a few seconds because it's not completely done deleting it yet.

Why don't you just open the file for writing, instead of deleting and recreating it?

Comment: I'll try that first then

Comment: this has worked splendid, is it because File.Delete() is asynchronous? Or something?

Comment: Yeah, the OS has some work to do, file operations are not instantaneous.

Comment: This may not be appropriate in all circumstances.  If the problem is a file lock from the OS, you may want use a "while" test for the File.Exists() to block until the file has been removed.

Comment: @Shaun I wasn't trying to address all circumstances, only the OP's. The solution to the original problem is clearly not to delete the file!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with the code you listed here and you need to provide more information for an answer.

***I.e.***, I created a console application that consists of the following c# code and it executes without a problem and creates the file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string saveFile = "test.txt";
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile))
                {
                    File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile);
                }

                File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile).Close();

                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Channels\\" + saveFile);

                //safe stuff to file
                streamWriter.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the file name had to be "hard coded" in, but you can see that the code is generally the same and if you copy it into a new console application you will also see that it works.

Comment: The thing is, the part before this is some string manipulation, which coulnd't produce this error. That only could produce some kind of "no such file" error.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.  Also, I tested to ensure that this works when the file already exists.  You should double-check that the file path you are supplying is valid (and that the directory exists, including the "Channels" folder) and that the user account your application is using has permissions to the file.

Comment: blipman, as everyone can test that your code doesn't produce an error, it lies elsewhere.

Comment: the current directory always exists. and above the try catch I've made the directory if it didn't exist. I will edit my post to include that.